# How to get touchpad working again on an Asus k53br?

Tags: 12.04, touchpad

[*This post was originally in Danish. Check post revisions.*](https://askubuntu.com/posts/177859/revisions)

I've had Ubuntu installed 12.04 for 3 days now. My touchpad worked fine right for 20 minutes after which it just stopped working for no reason?

I'm using an Asus k53br model. So how do I get it working again?

Comment: English:Did you maybe hit a button on your keyboard that disable the touchpad.                                                  Danish: Har du måske trykke på en knap på tastaturet, deaktivere touchpad'en.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the touchpad has been disabled. Try using the key combination for re-enabling it. OR to re-enable it via the command line follow these steps:

- Run `xinput list` in the terminal (the shortcut key combination for terminal is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>).
- Check whether you can see the touchpad in the list. In my computer it shows *AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad*.

[image]

- Now run the following command:

  `xinput set-prop 15 "Device Enabled" 1`

  Here `15` is the device id.

However, as this [Ubuntu Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection) says, it can be due to a bug. You should go to the mentioned page and check the section named **In case your Touchpad stops working after a while**.